# Which algorithm is used in sklearn SGDClassifier when modified huber loss is used?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

The documentation says:

> The loss function to be used. Defaults to ‘hinge’, which gives a
>   linear SVM. The ‘log’ loss gives logistic regression, a probabilistic
>   classifier. ‘modified_huber’ is another smooth loss that brings
>   tolerance to outliers as well as probability estimates.

When we use 'modified_huber' loss function, which classification algorithm is used? Is it SVM? If yes, how come it is able to give probability estimates, which is something it can't do with hinge loss?

Comment: [The docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict_proba) state that the modified_huber loss leads to calibrated responses that are converted to probabilities using an affine transformation (normalization).

Answer (score 0):

The modified Huber loss is equivalent to a quadratically smoothed SVM with gamma = 2.

See also https://www.quora.com/What-algorithm-is-used-in-sklearn%E2%80%99s-SGDClassifier-when-a-modified-huber-loss-is-used/